# Android java reference to object being destroyed

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have set up custom horizontal paging in my app with lets say 5 pages.  Each page has its own ListView and ListView Adapter.  In my main Activity class, I have an ArrayList of custom objects that I use to hydrate each ListView.

So in my main class, I can call:

```
lvAdapter.setItems(items);
```

Works fine.

But when I call:

```
lvAdapter.clearItems();
```

I only want it to clear the items in the ListView, but it actually removes all the items from my ArrayList for that object.  I suppose the Adapter is only holding a reference?

Adapter clearItems:

```
public void clearItems()
{
      this.items.clear();  //this will remove the object in the ArrayList
      this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

What I am trying to do is setItems on actively visible pages and clearItems for those pages that are not visible.  Because I am dealing with out of memory crashes when I load all the pages at once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clear the adapter reference for that `ListView` e.g. `listView.setAdapter(null)`

I would also read up on efficient `Adapter` implementations, there are several things you can do to reduce memory footprint e.g. recycling views properly in `getView(...)`